# What is web map marker called?

Tags: cartography

I'm referring to this icon

[image]

I'm just curious as to its origins and what the name of the symbol is. If memory serves, Google Maps introduced it, and the other mapping libraries adopted it.

Would anybody know what the symbol is called or is it just a "map marker"?

Did it exist before web maps or is purely a product of the web map age?

Or is just a stylized pin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jens Rasmussen, one of the inventors of Google Maps, a Danish computer programmer is credited with the creation of what is officially known as the `map pin` or `pushpin`.

See this [Who Made Google’s Map Pin?](http://6thfloor.blogs.nytimes.com/2011/04/18/who-made-googles-map-pin/?_php=true&_type=blogs&_r=1) (New York Times article) which is referenced in his official [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jens_Eilstrup_Rasmussen).

Answer (score -2):

It's called a Compass Rose in article before this.

Comment: But the Compass Rose is [this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/31/Compass_rose_simple_plain.svg/1200px-Compass_rose_simple_plain.svg.png). Could you add a reference?